# Python Read Excel file with Error - "We Found a problem with some content..."

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

Here is my problem. We have an Excel based report that business users enter comments into two separate fields, as well as selecting a code form a drop down. We then have a manual process that collects those files and pushes the comments and codes to a Snowflake table to be able to use in various reports.

I am trying to improve the process with a Python script that will collect the files, copy them to a staging_folder location, then read in the data from the sheet, append it all together, do some cleanup and push to Snowflake. The plan is that this would be completely automated - but this is where we run into issues.

Initial step works perfectly. I have a loop that grabs the files based on the previous business day date, copies them to a staging folder. There are typically 32 files each day.

Next step reads those files to append to a dataframe. Here is the function that is loading the Excel files in my Python script.

```
def load_files():
file_list = glob.glob(file_path + r'\*')
df = pd.DataFrame()
print("Importing data to Pandas DF...")
for file in file_list:
    try:
        wb = load_workbook(file)
        ws = wb["Daily Outs"]
        data = ws.values
        cols = next(data)[1:]
        data = list(data)
        idx = [r[0] for r in data]
        data = (islice(r, 1, None) for r in data)
        data_1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=cols)
        df = df.append(data_1, sort=False)

        print(file + " Imported to Df...")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: " + e + " When attempting to open file: " + file)
        # error_notify(e)
print(df.head(10))
return df
```

The problem is when we have files that have some sort of corruption. The files when opened manually will show an error like the one below.

[image: Error when manually opening XLSX corrupted file]

I thought with my try, except code above this would catch an error like this and alert me with the error_notify(e) function. However, we get a result where the Python script crashes with an error like this:  zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred.

There is more to the error, but I only copied & pasted this part in some communication with some folks int he office. Impossible to replicate the error on our own - I have no idea how the files get corrupted in this way - except that there are multiple people accessing the files throughout the day.

The way to make the file readable is completely manual - we must open the file, get that error, hit yes, and save the file over the existing one. Then re-launch the script. But since the try, except isn't catching it and alerting us to the failure, we have to run the script manually to see if it works or not.

Two questions - am I doing something incorrect in my try, except command? I am admittedly weak in error catching so my first thought is there is more I can do there to make that work. Secondly, is there a Python way to get past that error in the Excel workbook files?

Here is the error text:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:/Replenishment/Reporting/00 - I&A Replenishment/02 - Service
Level/Daily Outs Comment Capture/Python/daily_outs_missed_files.py", line 48, in load_files
wb = load_workbook(file)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 314, in load_workbook
data_only, keep_links)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in **init**
self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1222, in **init**
self._RealGetContents()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1289, in _RealGetContents
raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Replenishment/Reporting/00 - I&A Replenishment/02 - Service Level/Daily Outs Comment Capture/Python/daily_outs_missed_files.py", line 123, in <module>
main()
  File "G:/Replenishment/Reporting/00 - I&A Replenishment/02 - Service Level/Daily Outs Comment Capture/Python/daily_outs_missed_files.py", line 86, in main
df_output = df_clean()
  File "G:/Replenishment/Reporting/00 - I&A Replenishment/02 - Service Level/Daily Outs Comment Capture/Python/daily_outs_missed_files.py", line 68, in df_clean
df = load_files()
  File "G:/Replenishment/Reporting/00 - I&A Replenishment/02 - Service Level/Daily Outs Comment Capture/Python/daily_outs_missed_files.py", line 61, in load_files
    print("Error: " + e + " When attempting to open file: " + file)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "BadZipFile") to str
```

Comment: Pandas uses xlrd to parse excel workbooks. Could you try opening the corrupt Excel file with xlrd without the pandas wrapper code and post the error trace? xlrd tutorial can be found at https://github.com/python-excel/tutorial and here are some internals how it uses the xlrd api https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py , might help to understand the anatomy of your data and the error

Comment: oh, there is this alternative python library for handling Excel format documents https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ which is in active development and with active users and issues , it might be worth a try as well ... 

and btw, the zip error message actually makes sense, the format is just a zipped xml Microsoft has adopted it in Office for some time https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk , https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/open-xml-formats-and-file-name-extensions-5200d93c-3449-4380-8e11-31ef14555b18

Comment: Thanks, will try that - was reading about xlrd, but hadn't gotten around to testing it out with that. I will be storing some corrupted files to make it easier to test - because we can go a week or two with no corrupted files lately due to many folks being furloughed. Much bigger issue pre-COVID, but want to solve it nonetheless.

Comment: Can you clarify in the question which of the two related but separable issues you want to focus on : 1) using try/except properly with bad file(s) or 2) finding the cause of the file corruption problems. With no reproducibility/no control of the environment/software used to modify those Excel files solving 2 will be a challenge (macros? Some app writing bad parts of xlsx using Open XML SDK?). Focusing on 1, can you get a corrupted input file, run your python script and show the full trace? List your python modules/interpreter versions.

Comment: We definitely want to focus on issue 1 - we are in the infancy of a web portal for some of this reporting that would solve all the issues - but that could be months or years away. And issue 2 we have no control over, as you correctly pointed out. I have setup a folder to try and capture files when they are corrupted and working on a process so i can grab the full stack trace to share.

Comment: Best of luck with the project, learning python's try/catch and exceptions. There is one thing I do not understand from your question. What do you mean by "Python script crashes with an error like this: zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred."? The exception was not caught, for loop control flow did not progress to the next file and your python process did not finish with exit code 0? if that is the case then some exception not descending from the Exception class must have been thrown by pandas or lib/proc it uses.

Comment: I have just received a bad but repairable xlsx file from a client, which I might be able to use in tests and help close the issue. When treated with unzip from command line it generates an error message "error: missing 1 bytes in the zipfile" and "bad CRC" for one of the components in an "attempt to seek before beginning of zipfile
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)" . @Mke Heitz is this still a problem that you need to solve?

Comment: @predmod - after your advice earlier and my code revisions, we have had zero script failures and are pushing it into production reporting use. I would be very interested in seeing anything you are able to do though  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your try/except code looks correct. All user defined exceptions in python should be classes based on Exception. See [BaseException](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException) and 
and [Exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException) in python documentation : 
"Exception (..) All user-defined exceptions should also be derived from this class" see also [the exception class hierarchy tree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) at the end of the python doc sesction.

If your python script "crashes" it means one of the library procedures throws an exception which is not based on the Exception class, something that "should not" be. You could look at the Traceback and try catching the offending exception type separately, or find what part of the source code and which library is the cause, fix it and submit a PR. Here are two examples of a good and bad way of deriving own exceptions

```
class MyBadError(BaseException):
    """
    my bad exception, do not make yours that way
    """
    pass
```

instead of recommended

```
class MyGoodError(Exception):
    """
    exception based on the Exception
    """
    pass
```

Where and what exactly fails is a bit of mystery still but the problems with your exception from the Traceback is not new, see [zipfile.BadZipfile issue in pandas discussion](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26813). Note that xlrd used by pandas to read Excel workbooks data is currently a "no-maintainer-ware" [declaration about xlrd from the authors](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-excel/P6TjJgFVjMI/g8d0eWxTBQAJ) and in case of any issues the recommendation is to use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead or fix any issues yourself (pandas maintainers are doing pontius pilate on that, but happily use xlrd as a dependency). I suggest you catch the BadZipfile as a special known corruption error separately from all other exceptions, see [python error handling tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)  for example code (you probably already have seen it, this is for other readers). If that does not work I can trace it in the source code of your libraries / python modules to the exact offending section and find the culprit, if you reach out directly.

Comment: Hey @predmod - thanks for this info. I had a few days of the past 30 where the script failed. Working on trying to clean this up. I took your advice and am trying to read in the files using openpyxl instead of relying on pandas to read the excel files. However, I get the same error... I will past error in as well - but it's pretty much what you referenced earlier. I am going to attempt to build my own error class as you suggest - wish me luck!